# Right click on JButton to lock it and change its colour Java

Tags: java, jbutton, right-click

I am a beginner at java so am attempting to create a minesweeper game. I have a grid full of JButtons that when clicked reveal numbers or mines.

I want to add "flags" so when I right click on any button it changes colour - showing it has been flagged and is 'locked' so it cannot be clicked on unless right clicked.

Here are my buttons

```
public void buttons()
{
    // Creating the grid with buttons
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20));
    // Button grid
    for (int x = 0; x < buttons.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < buttons.length; y++)
        {
            buttons[x][y] = new JButton();
            buttons[x][y].addActionListener(this);
            grid.add(buttons[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

I attempted to create this right click functionality but I am currently stuck and would like some help.

```
public void flag()
{
    buttons.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            JButton rightClick = new JButton("Right Click");
            rightClick.addActionListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: and by being 'stuck' you mean what exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing this (right-clicking a button and when you do it changes colour). I am aware that I need MouseListeners and MouseAdapters but I'm not sure how

Comment: check out `MouseEvent` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html - you will need to detect clicking of button 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would process user events on a button via the button's `ActionListener`, what you want to try and do is stop the user from trigger the buttons `ActionListener`, the easiest way that you can do this is disable the button...

Normally, I don't like using `MouseListener`s on buttons as this is not normally the best way to ascertain user interaction, but in this case, it's the requirement

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton btn;

        public TestPane() {

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            btn = new JButton("O");
            btn.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            add(btn);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("You clicked me");
                }
            });

            btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        btn.setEnabled(!btn.isEnabled());
                        if (btn.isEnabled()) {
                            btn.setText("O");
                        } else {
                            btn.setText("X");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```